# python conditional combination

Tags: python, combinations

I have 3 list

```
list1= [min_0,min_1...min_150] consists of minimum indexes which has usually has 50-150 elements,  
list2= [max_0,max_1...max_150] consists of maximum indexes which has usually has 50-150 elements,  
list3= [min_0,max_0,max_1,min_1 ...max_149,min_150]
```

`list3` is joint of `list1` and `list2` and it is ordered. list3 has generally has 200-300 elements.

I want to create  5 elements `[x0,x1,x2,x3,x4]` combinations from `list3` that fits to 2 conditions with itertools of python.

condition 1: x0,x2 and x4 must in `list1`  and `x1, x3` must in `list2`   or  x0,x2, x4  must in `list2`  and x1, x3 must in list1

condition 2 : x4-x0 <=89

the problem is performance. Possible combinations for (300,5) is 19,582,837,560 . I have tried the split list3 to n parts and get some good performance but in this case, I have missed some possibilities which fit my conditions.

I hope the question is clear. How can I get the best performance? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid billions of iterations, you will need to simplify the combination domains.  This will be easier using sets.

So lets say your 3 lists are actually sets:

```
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
set3 = set(list3)
```

You have two patterns to look for:

Lets do part 1:

```
elements of list3 where x0,x2,x4 are in list1 and x1,x3 are in list2
```

x0,x2,x4 will be combinations of 3 out of `set3 & set1`

x1,x3    will be combinations of 2 out of `set3 & set2`

The 5 value tuples will be the product of these combinations:

```
part1 = { (x0,x1,x2,x3,x4) for x0,x2,x4 in combinations(set3&set1,3) 
                                        if x4-x0 <= 89
                           for x1,x3    in combinations(set3&set2,2) }
```

the second part uses the same approach but with the odd/even elements from the other lists:

```
part2 = { (x0,x1,x2,x3,x4) for x0,x2,x4 in combinations(set3&set2,3) 
                                        if x4-x0 <= 89
                           for x1,x3    in combinations(set3&set1,2) }
```

And the result is the union of the two parts:

```
result = part1 | part2
```

Depending on the data, this could still be in the millions of combinations but this method will greatly reduce the number of invalid combinations that need to be filtered out by conditions.

If that is still not fast enough, you should consider writing your own combinations function to optimize applying the set3 filter and x4-x0<89 condition within the combinatory logic.  (i.e. a 3 level nested loop giving (x0,x4,x2) that skips x4 values that don't fit the condition, preferably from sorted lists  to allow short circuiting)

*Note that if any of your lists contain duplicate values, you will definitely need to write your own filtering and combination functions to obtain pre-filtered subsets before multiplying 3-tuple and 2-tuple combinations*

[EDIT] here is an example of how to write the custom combination function.  I made it a generator in order to avoid creating a result set with a hundred million elements.  It only generates valid combinations and applies condition 2 as early as possible to avoid useless iterations through invalid combinations:

```
m = 150
n = 200
list1 = list(range(m))
list2 = list(range(m,2*m))
list3 = list(range(2,2*n,2))

def combine(L1,L2,L3):
    S3 =set(L3)
    inL1 = [x for x in L1 if x in S3]
    inL2 = [x for x in L2 if x in S3]
    for evens,odds in [(inL1,inL2),(inL2,inL1)]: # only generate valid combinations
        for p0,x0 in enumerate(evens[:-2]): 
            for p4,x4 in enumerate(evens[p0+2:],p0+2):
                if abs(x4-x0)>89: continue # short circuit condition 2 early
                for x2 in evens[p0+1:p4]:
                    for p1,x1 in enumerate(odds[:-1]):
                        for x3 in odds[p1+1:]:
                            yield (x0,x1,x2,x3,x4)
                                
print(sum(1 for _ in combine(list1,list2,list3))) # 230488170
```

The 230,488,170 combinations were produced in 22 seconds on my laptop.

Here are the first few combinations in my example:

```
for combo in combine(list1,list2,list3): print(combo)
            
(2, 150, 4, 152, 6)
(2, 150, 4, 154, 6)
(2, 150, 4, 156, 6)
(2, 150, 4, 158, 6)
(2, 150, 4, 160, 6)
(2, 150, 4, 162, 6)
(2, 150, 4, 164, 6)
(2, 150, 4, 166, 6)
(2, 150, 4, 168, 6)
(2, 150, 4, 170, 6)
(2, 150, 4, 172, 6)
(2, 150, 4, 174, 6) ...
KeyboardInterrupt
```

If you get hundreds of millions of valid combinations, you may need to rethink the way you're processing the data because you will run into performance and memory problems at every corner.

Comment: thanks a lot Alain for your quick answer . Lists have no duplicate values. You are right problem is combination domain. I try sets but combinations(set3&set2,3)  still consuming more time. I use distinct_combinations function  from  more_itertools  library. I am not sure is there any better performane functions for combination.

Comment: See Edit for a custom combination function

Answer (score 0):

use a function for condition 1. then apply it onto condition 2. that way condition 1 well have precise usage.